# Bad synchronization between Chat.SE & inbox

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, global-inbox

As I have a bad-time with my dial-up (like I get *logged out of SE* sometimes if I refresh the page), I don't spend much time in chat this week. But, this had happened 3 times in chat. I chat with someone and after sometime, I get into the main site. When I'm in the site, I get notified by my inbox: `3 new replies` (based on how much times I get pinged) which is totally ridiculous and it's annoying. I mean, I mostly suffocate before I enter into the chat room (due to my dial-up). And, this makes me suffocate more...

[image: Proof, if you want require...]

In h-bar, We also have a chat session once every two weeks. The chat notification says,
`A chat session is going to start within 10 mins`.

But in the main site, it says: `visit our Physics chat session going on right now`.

I don't know whether they both are correlated, but seems to me like a *relationship*. Can someone tell me more about this?

Comment: They are hosted on separate servers, and so there's probably a synchronization time that you're experiencing.